# How to use orWhere to combine results in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to find the slugs complete and incomplete model TaskboardColumn, then I only want the values of the user and the project.

Here is what I've tried:

Model

```
public static function projectOpenTasks($projectId, $userID=null)
{
    $taskBoardColumn = \App\TaskboardColumn::where('slug', 'incomplete')->first();
    $taskBoardColumn2 = \App\TaskboardColumn::where('slug', 'inprogress')->first();
    $projectTask = \App\Task::where('tasks.board_column_id', $taskBoardColumn->id)->orWhere('tasks.board_column_id', $taskBoardColumn2->id);

    if($userID)
    {
        $projectIssue = $projectTask->where('user_id', '=', $userID);
    }

    $projectIssue = $projectTask->where('project_id', $projectId)
        ->get();

    return $projectIssue;
}
```

Controller

```
$this->openTasks = Task::projectOpenTasks($this->project->id);
```

View

```
<ul class="list-task list-group" data-role="tasklist">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-role="task">
        <strong>@lang('app.title')</strong> 
        <span class="pull-right"><strong>@lang('app.dueDate')</strong></span>
    </li>
    @forelse($openTasks as $key=>$task)
        <li class="list-group-item row" data-role="task">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                {{ ($key+1).'. '.ucfirst($task->heading) }}
            </div>
            <label class="label label-danger pull-right col-xs-4">{{ $task->due_date->format($global->date_format) }}</label>
        </li>
    @empty
        <li class="list-group-item" data-role="task">
            @lang('messages.noOpenTasks')
        </li>
    @endforelse
</ul>
```

With this code I'm getting all the tasks, and I need just this project's tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grouping to achieve this

```
$projectTask = \App\Task::where(function($q) {
      $q->where('tasks.board_column_id', $taskBoardColumn->id);
      $q->orWhere('tasks.board_column_id', $taskBoardColumn2->id)
})->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

orwhere is used in places where only one of the query has to run. just like `and` keyword in programming orwhere is used in sense of query.

following is the code snippet -

```
$projectTask = $query->where('tasks.board_column_id', $taskBoardColumn->id)
      ->orWhere('tasks.board_column_id', $taskBoardColumn2->id)
      ->get();
```